# Testing JSON posts in Golang

Tags: json, unit-testing, post, go, client

I am trying to test a route I created to handle POSTing JSON data.

I am wondering how to write a test for this route.

I have the POST data in a `map[string]interface{}` and I am creating a new request like so:

```
mcPostBody := map[string]interface{}{
    "question_text": "Is this a test post for MutliQuestion?",
}
body, err = json.Marshal(mcPostBody)
req, err = http.NewRequest("POST", "/questions/", bytes.NewReader(body))
```

However, `t.Log(req.PostFormValue("question_text"))` logs a blank line so I don't think I am setting the body correctly.

How can I create a POST request with JSON data as the payload in Go?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Because that's the body of the request, you access it by reading `req.Body`, for [example](http://play.golang.org/p/U7izRJjfo8):

```
func main() {
    mcPostBody := map[string]interface{}{
        "question_text": "Is this a test post for MutliQuestion?",
    }
    body, _ := json.Marshal(mcPostBody)
    req, err := http.NewRequest("POST", "/questions/", bytes.NewReader(body))
    var m map[string]interface{}
    err = json.NewDecoder(req.Body).Decode(&m)
    req.Body.Close()
    fmt.Println(err, m)
}
```

//edit updated the code to a more optimized version as per elithrar's comment.

Comment: Don't forget to close the response body. You can also use `json.NewDecoder(resp.Body).Decode(&m)` to optimise: http://play.golang.org/p/S4uIelEC5R (see http://jmoiron.net/blog/crossing-streams-a-love-letter-to-ioreader/)